# UITextField not selectable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, textfield, viewdidload

I'm attempting to create a sign in screen for an app I'm working on. Right now I have two UITextFields with an image view behind them. When I try to click on a text field to enter text, nothing happens. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out this problem but can't find anyone who has had a similar problem. In my LoginViewController's viewDidLoad method I have the following code:

`

```
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h@2x.png"];

    UITextField *username = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 320, 140, 30)];
    username.placeholder = @"username";
    username.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    username.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    username.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    username.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [splashView addSubview:username];

    UITextField *password = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 365, 140, 30)];
    password.placeholder = @"password";
    password.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    password.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    [splashView addSubview:password];

    [self.view addSubview:splashView];
`
```

any help or advice would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the place to add Image:

```
  [super viewDidLoad];
UIImageView *splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h@2x.png"];

 // The image behind
 [self.view addSubview:splashView];

UITextField *username = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 320, 140, 30)];
username.placeholder = @"username";
username.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
username.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
username.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
username.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
// Change this
[self.view addSubview:username];

UITextField *password = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 365, 140, 30)];
password.placeholder = @"password";
password.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
password.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
//And change this
[self.view addSubview:password];
```

If you are another image for the other textField add to view first than this.

Comment: Ok. I just changed the code; its still not allowing me to edit the text fields though :/

Comment: Sorry I forgot these changes. Other option is make enable splashView to user interaction. But now must work.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. The adding subviews to splashview instead of self.view was the problem. Much appreciated

Comment: No exactly. The problem was that by default UIImageView has userInteractionEnable = NO. In fact your first code, also work if you add at the end:  splashView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; Sorry but the first time I didn´t see than you are adding your textField to your imageView.